# Is that possible one machine(only can use one ip and one port) use tcpclient connect to multiple servers

Tags: tcpclient, modbus

My problem is i have only one machine which have one ip(192.168.1.2) and one port(502), but we have to get informations from more than one services. Is that possible to use multiple tcpclients to connect to different servers at the same time? or other solutions please?? by the way, i encounter this problem when read different Modbus server to get device realtime information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can solve the problem by using SetSocketOption to reuse address and port.

```
    var masterClient = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
    masterClient.Client.SetSocketOption(
                                    SocketOptionLevel.Socket, 
                                    SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 
                                    true);
    masterClient.Connect(address.ToString(), 502);
```